# Record document search in SharePoint 2013

Tags: search-results, records-center

I’ve number of site collections where all documents are stored and IM policy is applied to move document to record center. Once document is moved to record center short cut(stub) icon is available at original document library and SharePoint convert document original location to aspx page (same name as document name) saying document is moved to record center on so and so date.

Now when user search for document it returns two results, one is short cut (as a .aspx page not with original file extension) and another is from record center.

**What I want do is:**
When user search for record document then it should return only one document and appear as normal document with pad lock(record icon) result instead of .aspx result. And on mover hover (search result display templates for short cut (stub)) it should display URL to record document in record center and record date.

Any Idea how we can achieve it?

Comment: Do you need to return aspx pages in your results? If not you could trim them. If you do, you could consider a record only search option.

Comment: Search for document (record) from original location which is now convert to .aspx page but in actual  result should have document icon with pad lock and record information on hover menu. 
Is any or we can identify this document is now record?